# python split a unicode string by 3-bytes utf8 character

Tags: python, regex, unicode

suppose that we have a unicode string in python,

`s = u"abc你好def啊"`

Now I want to split that by no-ascii characters, with result like

`result = ["abc", "你好", "def", "啊"]`

So, how to implement that?

Comment: Does the question actually have anything to do with the UTF-8 encoding of the characters , as the title suggests? It sounds like you just want to split a Unicode string into groups of ASCII vs. non-ASCII codepoints.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With regex you could simply split between "has or has not" a-z chars.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall('([a-zA-Z0-9]+|[^a-zA-Z0-9]+)', u"abc你好def啊")
["abc", "你好", "def", "啊"]
```

Or, with all ASCIIs

```
>>> ascii = ''.join(chr(x) for x in range(33, 127))
>>> re.findall('([{}]+|[^{}]+)'.format(ascii, ascii), u"abc你好def啊")
['abc', '你好', 'def', '啊']
```

Or, even simpler as suggested by @Dolda2000

```
>>> re.findall('([ -~]+|[^ -~]+)', u"abc你好def啊")
['abc', '你好', 'def', '啊']
```

Comment: Technically, the question asked about any ASCII character, not just alphanumeric ones. Of course, the example doesn't make it clear if that's an issue or not, I'm just saying.

Comment: Arguably, you could just use `[ -~]`. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
s = u"abc你好def啊"
status = ord(s[0]) < 128 
word = ""
res =[]

for b, letter  in zip([ ord(c) < 128 for c in s ], s):
      if b != status:
          res.append(word)
          status = b
          word = ""
      word += letter
res.append(word)

print res
>> ["abc", "你好", "def", "啊"]
```

Comment: Nice solution, and I find that I could change 128 to 0x07FF to split that by 2-bytes characters! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

```
s = "abc你好def啊"
filter(None, re.split('(\w+|\W+)', s))
```

works in python 2.x versions

Comment: `>>> list(filter(None, re.split('(\w+|\W+)', s)))` Result `['abc你好def啊']`

Comment: @C14L returns `[u'abc', u'\u4f60\u597d', u'def', u'\u554a']` for me can you check again

Comment: Still getting `['abc你好def啊']`. Maybe a Python 2 v 3 difference? (btw, I didn't downvote your answer)

Comment: I'm on python2.7, also list() is unnecessary since the result returns a list.

Comment: Either way, splitting into words wasn't really what OP asked for.

Comment: @Dolda2000 trying our best to understand the gaps the OP has left for us to fill

Comment: Yep, its Py2 v 3. In Python 3, I get a `<filter>` object with only one item after coercing to `list`. In Py2, I get a the `list` back as you said.

Comment: That's actually interesting, because it seems to mean that Python3's `re` module documentation lies, as it states that `\w` is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

Comment: @Dolda2000 :) not too sure about that but I have been doing corpus analysis using this for quite sometime, will readup

Comment: Actually, I read it too quickly. It actually states that, on Unicode strings, `\w` includes all Unicode alpha-numeric characters as well.

Comment: @Dolda2000 thanks i edited the answer to mention python version

Answer (score 0):

Just ... split.

```
[s[i:i+3] for i in xrange(0, len(s), 3)]
```

http://ideone.com/PeoGaF

Comment: Huh? No, that's Python 2 alright (there is a separate option in http://IdeOne.com/ if you want Python 3) though I used portable syntax as far as possible; this simple script snippet should work in Py3 as well, except `xrange()` is Python 2 specifically (in Python 3, use `range()`).